# "CS1513: } Expected" Error

Tags: c#, error-handling, compiler-errors

I keep getting "CS1513: } Expected" Error when I compile the below code. The Error occurs at the user_input method's opening bracket.

I'm new to C# and still learning. Sorry if I'm missing something obvious. I have already searched multiple forums and not found a solution. Thanks in advance for any help!

```
using System;
namespace App
{
class AppClass
{
    static void Main()
    {

    }
    void user_input()
    {
        public int input1;
        public int input2;
        public string operation;

        while (operation != "+" or operation != "-")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Would you like to Add or Subtract?");
            operation = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the first input:");
        input1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the second input:");
        input2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    }
    void do_math()
    {
        public int output;
        if (operation == "+")
        {
            output = input1+input2;
        } else {
            output = input1-input2;
        }
    }
    void display()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The answer is {0}", output);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: The `{`'s and `}`'s are not the issue. The issue is applying accessibility modifiers to local variables and the use of the word `or` instead of `||` in your while.

Comment: Also, you actually want **`&&`** instead of the `or` (`||`) statement; `opeartion` must be **neither** `+` nor `-`.

Comment: I guess the error message makes sense. Visual Studio has determined that the variable declarations take precedence, so it thinks you must declare them outside of a method and instructs you to add a `}` so that the variables are moved out.

Comment: Thanks guys! I moved the variables after the class and it compiled. Changed the "or " to "||". Thank you for the fast responses and showing me the right way!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should declare all your public variables outside your methods since you are using them in each function and VS consider this, also its not **`OR`** its **`||`**

```
using System;
namespace App
{
    class AppClass
    {
        public int input1;
        public int input2;
        public string operation;
        public int output;
        static void Main()
        {

        }
        void user_input()
        {
            while (operation != "+" || operation != "-")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Would you like to Add or Subtract?");
                operation = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Please enter the first input:");
            input1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter the second input:");
            input2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        }
        void do_math()
        {

            if (operation == "+")
            {
                output = input1 + input2;
            }
            else
            {
                output = input1 - input2;
            }
        }
        void display()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The answer is {0}", output);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: He should also need to remove "public" keywords from inside method declarations

Comment: Explain a bit more about the code issues, like the wrong or keyword, or why is needed to declare variables ouside the methods. I consider this the correct answer, but will be great if you provide more details.

Comment: @PedroFernandes added details